# bootstrap drop down not working even when on pressing the up and down keys are working fine

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple dropdown with the help of bootstrap dropdown.

I included all files and it is working fine in some places but in few pages, when I click on 3 dots, that are supposed to open the dropdown nothing is showing. When I press the down key, options pop-up.

I thought it was something, where things mess around with z-index. So I tried putting `Z-index:100;` but it didn't served my purpose. So have to put things here.

Thanks in advance who ever is going to put a single thought for helping. my code goes like this.

```
<span class="pull-right dropdown" >
    <a href="#" lass="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:7px;"></i> 
        <i class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:7px;"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:7px;"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" style="width:160px; right:14px;">
        <li><a style="width:155px;" href="edit_blog.php?b=<?php echo base64_encode($blog_id); ?>" target="_blank">Edit Blog</a></li>
        <li><a style="width:155px;" href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete_blog" id="delete_blog-<?php echo $blog_id;?>">Delete Blog</a></li>
    </ul>                              
</span>
```

In case something is messing up by not including the right files, these are the files I included:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hantr01n/

Comment: where is your css

Comment: bootstrap.min.css is already included

Comment: when i making snippets its show nothing

Comment: try the fiddle i shared @raj

Comment: You are using `<i class="fa fa-circle"...`. Did you included the Font Awesome css? By me it's working fine, so the cause is something in your project, that you didn't showed us.

Comment: as i mentioned the code dropdowns are working fine in some parts but even on same page , few drop downs are not working

Comment: Have you got some errors in console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.container a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
}

.container a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#news">Link</a>
</div>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

you need to try this

Comment: It's Ok. and please check left side mark and give me one Vote

Comment: already did, but my reputation is below 25 so my own vote doesn't count even if its my question.